# How to get a text's string from URL? See the video

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Have found a certain text on site via Chrome debugger. But the text itself ain't on the main page. So how can I get the value or text from the page if an element located inside many divs?

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOTXm2A6eRs)

Comment: Could you please improve your question?

Comment: I need to get that "109.224" text in Javascript.

Comment: "Ain't on the main page" I meant that I can't get this text or value from "Source Code" of main page. So I don't know where this string located.

Comment: Cannot access link to video. _"I need to get that "109.224" text in Javascript."_ How did you get the text to compose comment containing text?

Comment: `window.document.querySelector('CSS SELECTOR').textContent`

Comment: @Pyromonk can you show me it on example on http://www.forexlive.com/LiveCharts? So I need to get that string value of "USDJPY" which is on the right side of page.

Comment: @IvanV., it's inside of an iframe, last time I checked iframes were impervious to JavaScript. You can search the web for "how to get a value from within an iframe".